# What to do from stopping the program from exiting in Python before if command

Tags: python, if-statement, user-input

I used the following code for building a simple Python program which gets input from user.

```
Name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
Age = raw_input('Enter you age:')
Qualifications = raw_input('Enter you Qualification(s):')
A = raw_input()

print "Hello" +'.'+ "Your Name is " + Name + ". " + "Your Age is " + Age + ". " + "Your Qualification(s) is/are:" + Qualifications + "." 
print "If the above data is correct, type yes. If not, type no. Typing no will restart he program and make you write the form again." + A
if A in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']:
    print 'Thanks for your submission'
if A in ['No' , 'no' , 'NO' ,'n' , 'N']:
    reload()
```

The program finishes before the if command.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for the code to finish before the `if` command

Comment: Have you considered that if `A` is anything but one of the variations of Yes or No, your program will finish?

Comment: you might want to move `A = raw_input()` below the two lines starting with `print`. currently the user has to confirm before he sees the instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give anything but `['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']` or `['No' , 'no' , 'NO' ,'n' , 'N']`, your program will finish and not execute any of the statements in their respective `if`-clauses.

The `reload()` function will not do what you expect. It's used to reload a module and should be used inside the interpreter. It also requires a previously imported `module` as it's argument, calling it without will raise a `TypeError`.

So in order to actually ask the questions again, you'll need a loop. For example:

```
while True:
    name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
    age = raw_input('Enter your age: ')
    qualifications = raw_input('Enter your Qualification(s): ')

    print "Hello. Your name is {}. Your age is {}. Your qualifications are: {}".format(name, age, qualifications)
    quit = raw_input("Is the above data correct [yY]? ").lower() # notice the lower()
    if quit in ("y", "yes"):
        break
    else:
        # If the input was anything but y, yes or any variation of those.
        # for example no, foo, bar, asdf..
        print "Rewrite the form below"
```

If you now input anything else than a `y, Y` or any variation of `yes`, the program will ask the questions again.

Comment: I want the program to ask input again if the user types anything other than yes or no. If the user inputs no, the program must print 'Rewrite the form below' before asking the questions again.

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam That is what the program does, until infinity. I updated the answer to include that print. If you realllly want to check for the `no` case, just add a similar check as in the `yes` case.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `A raw_input` line after you print the "Your name is..." and stuff. Like this:

I also made the script keep asking to restart until the input is valid.

```
Name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
Age = raw_input('Enter you age:')
Qualifications = raw_input('Enter you Qualification(s):')

print "Hello" +'.'+ "Your Name is " + Name + ". " + "Your Age is " + Age + ". " + "Your Qualification(s) is/are:" + Qualifications + "."
print "If the above data is correct, type yes. If not, type no. Typing no will restart he program and make you write the form again."

yes = ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']
no = ['No' , 'no' , 'NO' ,'n' , 'N']

A = ''

while A not in (yes+no):   # keep asking until the answer is a valid yes/no
    A = raw_input("Again?: ")

if A in yes:
    print 'Thanks for your submission'
if A in no:
    reload()
```